# Webforms Grid doesn't display it's databound data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusions Grid control for Webforms(See [Demo](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/grid/masterdetails.aspx) that I based from).  I have a very simple UserControl with the following on it:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NAVPrices.ascx.cs" Inherits="Q5.NAVPrices" %>
<ej:Grid ID="PriceListGrid" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AllowSelection="True">
    <Columns>
        <ej:Column Field="ID" HeaderText="ID" IsPrimaryKey="True" TextAlign="Right" Width="125"></ej:Column>
        <ej:Column Field="Description" HeaderText="Description" Width="100" />
        <ej:Column Field="CustomerNo" HeaderText="Customer Number" Width="100" />
        <ej:Column Field="CustomerName" HeaderText="Customer" Width="150" />
        <ej:Column Field="Status" HeaderText="Status" Width="100" />
        <ej:Column Field="CreatedBy" HeaderText="Created" Width="100" />
        <ej:Column Field="ApprovedBy" HeaderText="Approved" Width="100" />
    </Columns>
</ej:Grid>
Details Grid
<ej:Grid ID="PriceLineGrid" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <Columns>
        <ej:Column Field="ID" HeaderText="ID" IsPrimaryKey="true" TextAlign="Right" Width="75" />
        <ej:Column Field="PriceListId" HeaderText="PriceList ID" Width="80" />
        <ej:Column Field="Description" HeaderText="Description" Width="75" />
        <ej:Column Field="LastCost" HeaderText="Last Cost" TextAlign="Right" Width="75" Format="{0:C}" />
        <ej:Column Field="SubGroup" HeaderText="Sub Group" Width="80" />
        <ej:Column Field="MfgName" HeaderText="Mfg Name" Width="110" />
        <ej:Column Field="Comment" HeaderText="Comment" Width="110" />
    </Columns>
</ej:Grid>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#PriceListGrid").ejGrid({
                selectedRowIndex: 0,
                rowSelected: function (args) {
                    var priceListId = args.data.ID;
                    var detaildata = window.ej.DataManager(window.gridData).executeLocal(window.ej.Query().where("PriceListId", window.ej.FilterOperators.equal, priceListId, false).take(10));
                    var gridObj = $("#PriceLineGrid").ejGrid("instance");
                    gridObj.dataSource(window.ej.DataManager(detaildata.slice(0, 5)));
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

and then the following methods are called on `Page_Load()` in the code behind.

```
    public void GetPriceLists()
    {
        if (this.EntityId != null)
        {
            SetCustomerNoFromId(this.EntityId, this.EntityType);

            var priceLists = BusinessLayer.Company.GetPriceLists(this.CustomerNo);
            this.PriceListGrid.DataSource = priceLists;
            this.PriceListGrid.DataBind();
        }

    }

    private void GetPriceLineItems()
    {
        if (this.CurrentPriceListItem != null)
        {
            var priceLineItems = BusinessLayer.Company.GetPriceLineItems(this.CurrentPriceListItem);
            this.PriceLineGrid.DataSource = priceLineItems;
            this.PriceLineGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I have stepped through the code and my `IList<PriceList>` is being populated with objects from my Data Layer as I would expect and it's formed correctly that I can see.

This is what the 2 objects look like:

```
    [Serializable]
public class PriceList
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNo { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ApprovedBy { get; set; }  
}

[Serializable]
public class PriceLineItems
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string PriceListId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string LastCost { get; set; }
    public string SubGroup { get; set; }
    public string MfgName { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

---

EDIT

For reference this is the JavaScript that works:

```
    $(function() {
    var $data = $("#PriceLineGrid").ejGrid("instance")._dataSource();
    $("#PriceListGrid").ejGrid({
        selectedRowIndex: 0,
        rowSelected: function(args) {
            var priceListId = args.data.ID;
            var detaildata = ej.DataManager($data).executeLocal(ej.Query().where("PriceListId", ej.FilterOperators.equal, priceListId, false).take(10));
            var gridObj = $("#PriceLineGrid").ejGrid("instance");
            gridObj.dataSource(ej.DataManager(detaildata.slice(0, 5)));
        }
    });
});
```

My issue now is that I don't actually populate Grid2 on PageLoad with all rows because there are simply too many.  So I need to change this to call a method in my code behind...I will open a new thread for this.

Comment: In `GetPriceLineItems()`, you set the data source to `PriceLineItems`, whose declaration is not shown. Are you confusing this with `priceLineItems`?

Comment: Oops, you caught a typo on my part in my question only.  FIxed

Comment: do your getter methods return `List`, `IEnumerable`, or `IQueryable`? If not `List`, there's a chance that it hasn't tried to enumerate (from what is presumably your database), and is failing because the connection has been closed by the time the grid tries to load it. so try  `BusinessLayer.Company.GetPriceLists(this.CustomerNo).ToList();`

Comment: Why is 'GetPriceLists' public and 'GetPriceLineItems' private? Where are they called from? Do both grids fail to show their data?

Comment: @ChrisSchiffhauer Thanks, that was simply leftover from my many attempts at trouble shooting.  They are both `private`

Comment: Does it work if you move this to a page, rather than in a user control?

Comment: I fired up a test project and added these as a page instead and still nothing.

Comment: Did the data not populated in both grids?

Comment: @ChrisSchiffhauer Nope, I tried that.
@Madhu No but that is because I was never setting the `CurrentPriceLineItem`  holdover from my WPF days.  I need to figure out how to do that in ASP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, if both `grids` are not populated with grid then the following will be the reason.

**On Initial rendering**

The Syncfusion grid works well with `IEnumerable` and as Chris Schiffhauer suggested, change the `priceLists` and `priceLineItems` to `List`

```
priceLineItems.ToList();

 and

priceLists.ToList();
```

**On Master row selected**

And in the `rowSelected` event of `PriceListGrid` you have used `window.gridData` as the datasource to filter the detail grid(`PriceLineGrid`) data. But the `window.gridData` will not contain the `PriceListId` field and hence no data will be populated on row select too.

```
 var detaildata = window.ej.DataManager(window.gridData).executeLocal(window.ej.Query().where("PriceListId", window.ej.FilterOperators.equal, priceListId, false).take(10));
```

> window.gridData (which is reffered from jsondata.min.js) will contain JSON array which is used by Syncfusion samples grid.

So to filter the detail grid datasource based on master grid`s selected row value use the following code.

```
$("#PriceListGrid").ejGrid({
            selectedRowIndex: 0,
            rowSelected: function (args) {
                var priceListId = args.data.ID;
                var gridObj = $("#PriceLineGrid").ejGrid("instance");
                var detaildata = window.ej.DataManager(gridObj.model.dataSource).executeLocal(window.ej.Query().where("PriceListId", window.ej.FilterOperators.equal, priceListId, false).take(10));

                gridObj.dataSource(window.ej.DataManager(detaildata.slice(0, 5)));
            }
        });
```

In the above changed the `ej.DataManager(window.gridData)` to `ej.DataManager(gridObj.model.dataSource)`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was really close to what I needed for that step.  I added the working javaScript to my question as an Edit.  
My issue now seems to be that I am not actually populating the second grid with all rows like the sample assumes.  I have too many to do that and need to wait until a row from Grid1 is called so that Grid2 can start off filtered.

Comment: I am actually going to accept your answer since it is what led me to solve my first issue and then I'll start a new thread for my new question.  Seems like the proper thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Cast your `IList` variables to `List`:

```
public void GetPriceLists()
{
    if (this.EntityId != null)
    {
        SetCustomerNoFromId(this.EntityId, this.EntityType);

        var priceLists = BusinessLayer.Company.GetPriceLists(this.CustomerNo);
        this.PriceListGrid.DataSource = priceLists.ToList(); // here
        this.PriceListGrid.DataBind();
    }
}

private void GetPriceLineItems()
{
    if (this.CurrentPriceListItem != null)
    {
        var priceLineItems = BusinessLayer.Company.GetPriceLineItems(this.CurrentPriceListItem);
        this.PriceLineGrid.DataSource = priceLineItems.ToList(); // and here
        this.PriceLineGrid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion, silly oversight on my part!  However, it still doesn't display my data....